# Как пройтись по запросу where Mysql и PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Стоит задача найти элемент в таблицы данных:

```
SELECT * FROM `url_products` WHERE `article` LIKE 'ПЛИ-02231'
```

Он находит все элементы с данным артикулом,
Дальше надо пройтись по выдаче что бы приплюсовать остатки как это сделать?

Пробывал:

```
 SELECT MAX(id) FROM `url_products` WHERE `id` LIKE 'ПЛИ-02231'
 SELECT MIN(id) FROM `url_products` WHERE `id` LIKE 'ПЛИ-02231'
```

Что бы потом использовать цикл php, но мин и макс значение выводит одно и  тоже

Comment: Какая структура таблицы? Вероятно что вы совсем неверно строите запросы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во 2ой части запросов с max(`id`) у вас ошибка, должно быть вот так:

```
SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `url_products` WHERE `article` LIKE 'ПЛИ-02231'
```

WHERE `article` , а не WHERE `id`